# is there any diffrence to use nonlinear or liner activation function in single hidden layer network

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, loss-functions

I am working in a classification problem in which I use RBF with a single hidden layer. I want to use SoftMax activation function for the output layer. I already read some documents about the activation function of the output layer but can't find my answer. I try to write the equation for softmax and linear activation function and compare them. in my opinion yes they are different, but after I saw some documents I become confused so to become sure about I decide to ask it here.

is there any difference between linear and nonlinear activation function in a single hidden network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any difference between linear and nonlinear activation function in a single hidden network?

If you have a single-layer network with activations functions that are all linear, the network is a linear model -- the same as a linear regression. This is because compositions of linear functions are still linear. If the *last* layer is a softmax, but the hidden layer is linear, this is a logistic regression.

If you have a single-layer network with *nonlinear* hidden units, it is not equivalent to any linear model. It is expressly a nonlinear model.

Comment: I have RBF network so the hidden layer is nonlinear (using Gaussian kernel) and I use softmax function for the output layer, so according to your answer using the linear output layer is not equivalent to any nonlinear activation function like softmax?